# C# Uri with username as "domainname\username"

Tags: c#

I have a string like

```
<Scheme>:\\<domain>\<domainuser>:<EncryptedPassword>@servername\
```

I want to be able to create Uniform resource identifier (URI) and easy access the parts of the URI. For most part using C# Uri class works great. But I get invalid URI exceptions when user is provided as "domainname\domainuser".

How best to handle this in C#.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Did you mean `\ `? The comments section is finicky about the backslash business...

Comment: Indeed I tried to say "check if `\\` is allowed in that part" ... [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) section 3.2.1 don't seem to allow it user information...

Answer (score 2):

You must PercentEncode(/EscapeDataString) such strings.

Like in question above username **"xyz_domain\abc_user" must be encoded to "xyz_domain%5Cabc_user"** to before creating URI object.

Later after extracting you can do PercentDecode(/UnescapeDataString) of the string using  UnescapeDataString method from Uri Class.You can use UnescapeDataString Method from C# [Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Here is the code

```
public static string GetUsername(this Uri uri)
        {
            if (uri == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri.UserInfo))
                return string.Empty;
            var items = uri.UserInfo.Split(new[] { ':' });
            //Replace precent encoding in the username.
            var result = Uri.UnescapeDataString(items[0]);
            return result.Length > 0 ? result : string.Empty;
        }
```

Similar scheme can be applied to any part of the uri string. Just remember to UnescapeDataString the EscapeDataStrings.